# Javascript vibrant color chooser

Tags: javascript, colors, color-scheme

I am looking for a vanilla Javascript method to choose either hexadecimal or RGB color values for a blocky-but-continuous spectrum of colors. The method should be able to specify a number of divisions/blocks and return, in any way, colors that fit the following criteria:

- Vibrant: Not too dark or too light. I don't want to have black or white in there. The colors should be pretty bright in saturation, but just middling in lightness. Also, avoiding gray would be awesome but optional.
- Continuous: Each range/block's color should approximately match the past and future colors. The colors should "flow" in a way, not clash with each other. Colors should not repeat (it's a spectrum).
- Reproducible: If the method is given the same number of blocks but is run on a different machine at a different time, the colors chosen should be the same. If more divisions are added, the colors should only "shift", making the spectrum smoother, and decreasing the difference between consecutive colors.

This example was styled as randomly-sized HTML `div`s. I don't even have the HTML code for this.

[image: Example]

Any help or pointers would be awesome!

Comment: SO probably isn't going to be the best place for this sort of question but as a hint, if you want "Vibrant", you are probably going to want to generate them as HSB colours.

Comment: Interesting point. I'll take it that SO might not be the best place, but since I kinda need this done thousands of times every day, I thought that it's probably best to ask the developer crowd for a programmatic way to achieve this (that sounded sassy, but I didn't intend it at all). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Try looking into the HSL colour model. More specifically, look into specifying colours with Hue(0-360) Saturation(0-100%) Luminance(0-100%) Alpha(0-1). E.g a lime-green colour would be: `hsla(73, 100%, 50%, 1)`

Comment: @enhzflep I understand that `hsl` and `hsla` would both work in a CSS sense. But I really need either RGB or hex. As my comment in jdphenix's answer shows, I would really like a simple vanilla JS way to convert from `hsl` or `hsla` to RGB or hex. One dirty workaround would be to set an HTML element's color and re-read it, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Didn't think of the `hsl` values until Quirliom brought them up.

Comment: @fond42518 - converting between the colour-systems yourself isn't hard at all - there's more than a couple of implementations around to be found on the web - they're far, far, _far_ longer to implement than just getting the browser to convert for you. You don't even have to have a permanent, on-screen (even if invisible) element to do so. You can just set a style attribute of a temporary element, read it back as you mention and be done with it. No need to re-create a wheel when there's already a perfectly functioning one available.  ;)

Comment: @enhzflep I understand your point, but simplicity is key. If I'm doing this calculation often, the more efficient it is the better. And I am not able to implement external libraries (hence my not using the "more than a couple of implementations around to be found on the web"). I am seeking an "optimal" solution, or at least as close as I can get to one.

Comment: @fond42518 - another reason for using the browser. If _you_ do the calc, you have to do it in JS, which gets interpreted as text, JIT compiled to executable code and then finally executed. If the browser does it, it's native code all the way. You'll not write code that beats the browser in terms of speed (or size). Not today, next-week or ever in fact. Added to that, it's as simple as falling over - while a DIY approach is as hard as building a bridge and then crossing it. Browser compatibility is the only reason I would ever dream of rolling-my-own. (That's ***if*** the native method fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that I believe meets the requirements you've specified. Specifically -

- Vibrant - Eye of the beholder in my opinion, but it seems vibrant.
- Continuous - Created by modifying the hue value of an hsla color, which is by definition, around the color wheel.
- Reproducible - Output will match in any JavaScript engine.

```js
colorSpectrum = function(count) {
    if (count <= 0) { 
        throw new Error('Count must be atleast 1'); 
    }
    
    var h = 0,
        s = '75%', 
        l = '50%',
        a = 1,
        current = 0,
        colors = [],
        tohsla = function(h,s,l,a) {
            return 'hsla(' + h + ',' + s + ',' + l + ',' + a + ')';
        }
    
    while (current < count) {
        colors.push({
            h:h, 
            s:s, 
            l:l, 
            a:a
        });
        h += 360 / count; 
        current++; 
    }
    
    return {
        colors:colors.map(function(el) {
            return tohsla(el.h, el.s, el.l, el.a); 
        })
    }
};

var colors = colorSpectrum(24); 

colors.colors.forEach(function(color) { 
    var span = document.createElement('span'), 
        bodyWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).width, 10); 
    console.log(colors.colors.length);
    span.classList.add('color');
    span.style.backgroundColor = color; 
    span.style.width = bodyWidth / colors.colors.length + 'px'; 
    document.body.appendChild(span); 
});
```

```css
.color {
    height:12px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I need the function to output either RGB or hex. Is there any _simple_ vanilla way to convert to this?

Comment: @fond42518 There is not a vanilla built-in solution to convert to rgb, but the algorithm is pretty simple to implement, here's an overview here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL - If you want really *simple*, read the color of the element.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but I guess there's not much else to work with. Thanks for your contribution!